# Get some parameters for mail sent through ses in sns notification

Tags: c#, amazon-ses, amazon-sns

We are trying to track bouncing mails sent through `SES` using `SNS` notifications.

We have campaigns in our application and we want to suspend campaigns whose more then 5% emails are getting bounced.

Please suggest a way how we can send `campaign id` with mail so that we can get same back in `SNS` notification.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, the simplest thing to do may be to add the SES messageid that is generated each time an email is sent from SES into a database (dynamodb or rds or other) and add the campaign id to each record.

When a bounce notification comes in, lookup the messageid and findout what campaign it was sent from and mark it is bounced and then calculated if you have exceed the 5% threshold.